# Is there a term describing how fill trees are to forests as cycles?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, terminology

I am interested in the number of possible graphs in which every vertex and edge is part of exactly one cycle graph, including self loops.  Is there a term for this?  (I would call it a '1-cyclery'.)

Comment: I don't know of one. If there is one it may be somewhere in the vocabulary of _matroids_.

Comment: If you're including a single vertex with a self-loop as a 1-cycle, would you also include two vertices with a double edge as a 2-cycle? If so, then it would seem that "2-regular graph" may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think that would be okay, but I am not allowing infinitely long chains.